# How can we format email using Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have written a small code which collect 'text', 'email', and 'subject' form the spreadsheet and send gmail to the recipient. Google Script is working fine, however the width of the automated gmail is fixed. So when the length of 'text' changes gmail width doesn't change which leads to changes in text placement and that looks bit weird.

My Code example:-

```
function temp2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var emailTemplate2 = templateSheet.getRange("G1").getValue();
  var rec = templateSheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
  var sub = templateSheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
//  Logger.log(rec);
  MailApp.sendEmail(rec, sub, emailTemplate2);
}
```

First Image of my truncated email:-
[image]

Second Image of my truncated email:-
[image: image2]

In this mail 'May/December', '171/26131', and 'April/November' are the dynamic words. Due to which my second line of the mail (as you can see in this image) sometime ends at 'following' or sometimes at 'closed' (depending on the length of these three dynamic entries).

Ideally in my gmail width should be dynamic and it should end with the 'Period(.)' after the Month name in this case it is April/November. 
I would like to check that Do we have any sub-option in GAS through which we can make the 'width of the gmail dynamic'? I gone through `MailApp.sendEmail` Options in documentation but couldn't find more details.

Any suggestion in this regard will be very helpful.

Regards,

Alok

Comment: You can get a little more control over the email composition by using the htmlBody option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method "sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)" with the body parameter empty ("") and adding the options Json with the htmlBody key (which will be use instead of the body value).

In the htmlBody value (string) you can arrange the text as you want. In your case, you obtain the values from a sheet, so you can put all the html code directly and concatenate with the sheet value that's going to be the body of the email.

Here is a working example:

```
function temp2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var emailTemplate2 = templateSheet.getRange("G1").getValue();
  var rec = templateSheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
  var sub = templateSheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
  //  Logger.log(rec);
  MailApp.sendEmail(rec, sub, "", {
    htmlBody: '<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body><div style="width:1864px;">' + emailTemplate2  + '</div></body></html>'
  });
}
```

In there, i put all the content of the body inside a `<div>` element with the width property set to 1864px, you could adjust this as you need to fit all the body in one line.

Other options can be use html code inside the sheet cell, and format the text in there as you want, using `<div>`, `<p>`, `<br>`, `<strong>`, etc.

For further reading: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app